# How to overwrite an existing variable using another variable in batch files?

Tags: batch-file

In the following two (simplified examples) batch files I am having difficulty when I want to overwrite some variables:

### batch_test 1:

```
 @echo off
 set var=D:
 set var_2=%var%\DOMAIN
 set var_3=%var_2%\sub_domain
 call batch_test2.bat
 @echo %var%
 @echo %var_2%
 @echo %var_3%
```

### batch_test 2:

```
  @echo off
  if 1==1 (
      set var=E:
      set var_2=%var%\Component
      set var_3=%var_2%\comp1
  )
```

### output:

E:
D:\Component
D:\DOMAIN\comp1

### expected_output:

E:
E:\Component
E:\DOMAIN\comp1

How can I get the expected_output using multiple variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For batch_test 2 you should use delayed expansion and [tunneling](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=985):

```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if 1==1 (
      set var=E:
      set var_2=!var!\Component
      set var_3=!var_2!\comp1
  )
  endlocal & (
     set var=%var%
     set var_2=%var_2%
     set var_3=%var_3%
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

This is, again, the infamous early variable expansion problem: batch scripts substitute variables early, before a block starts.
that means %var_2% will be fixed to the first value. to get around that, use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and then surround the variable with "!" instead of "%".